# Does Spring Data Redis support Externalizable?

Tags: java, redis, deserialization, spring-data-redis

I am new to Redis things.
I have some Object which is `Externalizable`.
But Spring Data Redis is not working with these Objects.
Does Spring Data Redis need `Serializable` strictly or there is some way to work with `Externalizable` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data Redis supports different [serialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer) strategies to represent your objects in binary form so it can be stored in Redis.

One of the serialization formats is using [Java's serialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.html) mechanism via [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). There are no Spring Data specifics when using Java serialization.

Comment: That's not what I wrote. You can use all features that `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` provide. Have you actually tried it? If not, the whole discussion is pointless then.

Comment: Is it necessary to provide "no-argument constructor" for de-serialization ?
Is there any way, redis-java-client can do it automatically.